# Unable to find it out duplicate - perl

Tags: perl

I am traversing all files to get the desired one in some directory tree recursively, as soon as i am getting that files i doing some operation on them but before doing the operation i need to check whether i have performed operation on this file or not if yes then don't do it again else continue :

But the prob is, i am unable to find the way to check the condition :(

Here is my code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Find 'find';
use File::Spec;
use Data::Printer;

my ( $root_path, $id ) = @ARGV;
our $anr_name;
opendir my ($dh), $root_path;
my @dir_list = grep -d, map File::Spec->catfile( $root_path, $_ ), grep { not /\A\.\.?\z/ } readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;

my $count;
for my $dir (@dir_list) {
    find(
        sub {
            return unless /traces[_d]*/;
            my $file = $_;
            my @all_anr;
            #print "$file\n\n";
            my $file_name = $File::Find::name;
            open( my $fh, "<", $file ) or die "cannot open file:$!\n";
            my @all_lines = <$fh>;
            my $i         = 0;
            foreach my $check (@all_lines) {
                if ( $i < 10 ) {
                    if ( $check =~ /Cmd line\:\s+com\.android\..*/ ) {
                        $anr_name = $check;
                        my @temp = split( ':', $anr_name );
                        $anr_name = $temp[1];
                        push( @all_anr, $anr_name );
                        #print "ANR :$anr_name\n";
                        my $chk = check_for_dublicate_anr(@all_anr);
                        if ( $chk eq "1" ) {
                            # performed some action
                        }
                    }
                    $i++;
                } else {
                    close($fh);
                    last;
                }
            }
        },
        $dir
    );
}

sub check_for_dublicate_anr {
    my @anrname   = @_;
    my %uniqueAnr = ();
    foreach my $item (@anrname) {
        unless ( $uniqueAnr{$item} ) {
            # if we get here, we have not seen it before
            $uniqueAnr{$item} = 1;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could do with clarifying what you're trying to accomplish here. Do you need to check across invocations of the script (e.g. save state?). is `check_for_dublicated_anr` and example of you trying to do this already? Because that's just testing the contents of `@all_anr` each iteration. But if it's not, you can use a similar test on $File::Find::name to weed out duplicate filenames.

Comment: I am traversing all files to get the desired one , before doing any operation on that file i need trying to make sure that operation is happening first time only. Say like u need to raise some bug on defect tracking tool so that bug should not get raise duplicate i am trying to achieve this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify things with [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) and [`Path::Class::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class::Rule):

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use Path::Class;
use Path::Class::Rule;

my $root = ".";
my @dirs = grep { -d $_ } dir($root)->children();
my $iter = Path::Class::Rule->new->file->name(qr{traces[_d]*})->iter(@dirs);

my $seen;
while ( my $file = $iter->() ) {
    for ( $file->slurp( chomp => 1 ) ) {
        next unless /Cmd line:\s+(com\.android\.\S*)/;
        do_things( $file, $1 ) unless $seen->{$1}++;
    }
}

sub do_things {
    my ( $file, $str ) = @_;
    say "new $str in the $file";
}
```